# Can not take json data with angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, json

http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php

I want to take those data and print screen in my index.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="todoController">


    <p>Movie list page</p>
    <br>
    <p>click button to see movies</p>


    <div class="form-group" >
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
                <span class="fa fa-check"></span> count list movie</button>
            <span>
  count: {{count}}
</span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="listMovie()">
                <span class="fa fa-check"></span> list movie</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>the Movis you want to list is:</p>
    <p>list :{{list}}</p>


     <p>{{listed}}</p>
      <p>ss {{tasks}}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am doing in this angular.js file

```
    /**
 * Created by caneraydin on 16.03.2016.
 */
var app=angular.module('todoApp',[]);
app.controller('todoController',function($scope,$http){
 var urlBase="";

 $scope.toggle=true;

 $scope.selection = [];

 $scope.statuses=['ACTIVE','COMPLETED'];

 $scope.priorities=['HIGH','LOW','MEDIUM'];

 $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    $scope.addMovie=function(title,actors){
        $scope.title="title clicked "+title

        $scope.actors="actors clicked "+actors

        $scope.added="the movie '"+title+"' with those actors '"+actors+"' added successfully"
    },

    $scope.deleteMovie=function(id){
        $scope.id="id clicked "+id


        $scope.deleted="the movie with id '"+id+"' deleted successfully"
    },

    $scope.listMovie=function(list){
       $scope.tasks=[];
      $scope.list="list clicked"
       $scope.list="list+list"+list
      $scope.listed="the movies are listing:"+list
              $http.get( 'http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php').

            success(function (data) {

             $scope.tasks=data.name





}); 
};
  })
```

inside listmovie but it cant post data.

I tried to change to array but still same.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5xTe6v?p=preview

i changed the code according to comments but it is continuing. It cant show JSON data.

When i make

```
 function myError(response) {
    $scope.check = response;

     });
```

i get this:

```
{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/5xTe6v?p=preview i changed one quote two quotes but still same. It cant go inside of success in angularjs. I put variable to check if is going inside but it doesnot :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data your call returns doesn't have a name property directly..
Please change your code to this

```
$http.get( 'http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php').
            success(function (data) {
             $scope.tasks=data.products;
});
```

and in your html you can directly view your tasks as this

```
<p>ss {{tasks | json}}</p>
```

or view each product as this

```
<div ng-repeat="prod in tasks">Name: {{prod.name}}</div>
```

**EDIT**

In your plunker, see the console, it says

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This means CORS is not available on the server and so you can't access it from where you're accessing (same goes for the plunkr)

You need to enable CORS on your backend.

You can get help on this from this link probably: 
https://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working

Answer (score 0):

according to response from  http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php

```
{"products":[{"pid":"1","name":"sogan","price":"19.30","created_at":"2016-03-12 15:08:38","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"pid":"2","name":"faltak","price":"22.00","created_at":"2016-03-12 15:08:38","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],"success":1}
```

you should change this :

```
$http.get( 'http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php').

        success(function (data) {

         $scope.tasks=data.name});
```

to this one :

```
 $http.get( 'http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php').

        success(function (data) {

         $scope.tasks=data.products });
```

or this one:

```
 $http.get( 'http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php')

        .then(function (response) {

         $scope.tasks=response.data.products 
   });
```

Comment: It looks like CORS issue.. try to add 
 <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); on ttp://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php